# Is there something like the opposite of a JsonIgnore?

Tags: c#, json.net

The `JsonIgnore` attribute can be used to ignore certain properties in serialization. I was wondering if it is possible to do the opposite of that? So a JsonSerializer would ignore every property EXCEPT when there is a special attribute on it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes there is. When you mark your class with `[JsonObjectAttribute]` and pass the `MemberSerialization.OptIn` parameter, member [serialization is opt-in](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm). Then mark your members with `[JsonProperty]` to include them for serialization.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class Person
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // not serialized because mode is opt-in
    public string Department { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Or, one could use [data contract attributes](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DataContractAndDataMember.htm) to the same effect.

Comment: @dbc I do like the substitutes for the Json attributes. I picked the Json attributes because they allow for easy further customization in the future and they take the same effort to apply. Advantage of the data contract attributes is they are already familiar to most users.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to `MemberSerialization.OptIn` is using `DataContract`/`DataMember` attributes:

```
[DataContract]
public class Computer
{
  // included in JSON
  [DataMember]
  public string Name { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public decimal SalePrice { get; set; }

  // ignored
  public string Manufacture { get; set; }
  public int StockCount { get; set; }
  public decimal WholeSalePrice { get; set; }
  public DateTime NextShipmentDate { get; set; }
}
```

Source: http://james.newtonking.com/archive/2009/10/23/efficient-json-with-json-net-reducing-serialized-json-size